# How to read an object within an object in OfficeScript - interfaces and setValues()

Tags: typescript, office-scripts, excel-online

I'm currently learning Excel Office Script through API requests. Granted I'm not a programmer.

Here, something I do very easily in Jquery is giving me headaches in Excel Office Script. I cannot seem to be able to structure objects correctly in order to setValues on the page, and use the object in Power Automate.

My error in the end is related to the way I have to build my arrays in relation to the "interfaces". I still cannot figure it out, how to structure it:
The error is in the end, at setValues -- the dimensions are not correct for the setValues.

For understanding purpose : I'm requesting submissions of a JotForm directly into Excel Online so I cannot give my code fully. But I can show an edited Json and explain my process.

1° Excel office Script

```
    async function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook): Promise<void> {
        
        const workSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
        let fetchResult = await fetch(myApiQuery)
        
        let json: JSONData[] = await fetchResult.json();
        
        // From here, I don't need the complete answer, I filter the Json Object from ["content"]
        const result: JSONData[] = json["content"]
        const rows: (string | boolean | number)[][] = [];

// FROM HERE, I want to iterate through the object.
// Basically, the structure of my code should work like this : 
// iterate through "CONTENT" -> Iterate THROUGH "ANSWERS" -> IS "answer" UNDEFINED ? (if UNDEFINED : return empty, if not return the answer). 
//See JSON below.

        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(result)) {
           
            rows.push([value["id"],value["created_at"],value["answers"]])
                  
            for (const [subKey, subValue] of Object.entries(value["answers")) {
                if (typeof subValue["answer"] !== "undefined") {
                   rows.push([subValue["answer"]])
                }
                else {
                    rows.push([""])
                }
         }


     console.log(rows);
     const targetRange = workSheet.getRange('A2').getResizedRange(rows.length - 1, rows[0].length - 1);
     targetRange.setValues(rows);


return;


}


// This is what I understood will be important for Power Automate
   interface JSONData {
        id?:number
        created_at?:number
        answers?:SUBDATA;
    }

    interface SUBDATA{
            answer?:string;


    }
```

2°) Here is the JSON Object from my console.log (console.log(rows)). I edited personal info and cut it from the hudreds of rows. As you can see, in "ANSWERS" (plural), sometimes "answer" (singular) is defined, sometimes not. I need to be able to make a difference, return empty if it is undefine to keep a correspndance between questions and answers.

```
[
    {
        "id": "---",
        "form_id": "---",
        "ip": "---",
        "created_at": "2021-09-18 07:39:14",
        "updated_at": null,
        "answers": {
            "1": {
                "name": "vousAvez",
                "order": "6",
                "text": "QUESTION",
                "type": "control_head"
            },
            "2": {
                "name": "email",
                "order": "7",
                "text": "Email",
                "type": "control_email",
                "answer": "email Address" }
        }
    ],
    [""],
    [""],
    [""],
    ["emailAdress"],
    ["Name"],
    ["FristName"],
    [""],
    [""],
]
```

Here is an example that works in JQUERY

```
 $.each(responseText["content"], function (index, element) {
       items.push("<br/><span style='color:red'>" + element["id"] + " - " + element["created_at"] + "</span><br/><br/>");
       $.each(element["answers"], function (subIndex, subElement) {
          if (typeof subElement["answer"] !== "undefined") {
             items.push("<li id='" + subIndex + "'>" + subElement["name"] + "<span style='color:blue'> " + subElement["answer"] + "</span></li>");
          }
          else {
             items.push("<li id='" + subIndex + "'>" + subElement["name"] + ": </li > ");
          }
          items.push('<br/>');
          })
})
 $("<ul/>", {
       "class": "my-new-list",
       html: items.join("")
 }).appendTo("body");
```

Comment: It would be helpful to know what the expected output looks like. Could you please share a screenshot or table showing what the Excel worksheet should be after running your script (at least a truncated example version of it)?

Comment: Just an FYI, your JSON isn't valid. The first right bracket on line 21 should actually be a right curly brace.

Comment: You can try using tools like https://jvilk.com/MakeTypes/ to convert your json to an interface.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this [example in TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKA9GAEAmCmBmBLAdrGBDALuyLOwCd50BjWUUPQ4syAESxwG9RI3doAuSAZ0wJQBzANyt28APYEAtgH1EXXvyGiQ7XAAdufAchFi2JArCyxosrNuV7V6gK4bop85aW7BkAD6RkdgDZ+tuzoyDwA7oQ83Cxq6uwA2gDWsACeVu4AutEGcerI6NKw6So5uWxScATFNqVl+AAemNX6sWXsmCkaRW4lrW2QIeGEAPzNQbkAvjlTIDOgEJCw9QUafmgS8EpYiCQY2KAkEqGYe+gAggQE6CkAksgadk30jPEZkAC8kPE5MW0ARAo-tw-gBaMF-AA0tTYf0kMnk0CBkFB4KhfXUAI0SJRIMh0ORRhM+BcmGxACYAAxkgCMIIpAE4QdSAByQCkAdk4AGZ6ZxqQAWPHo9h-BxOYkWUncXwBNH-QYRAg8JG-fow6kq-H-fKFbEANwkdh4Zz1sAAXkK1bk-hVCNiAGyWq0YhpS5EARQAqgBRADKABUbgB5AByTudMI6XWxh2Q-AkflkAAsTIitewJnKrX8yZrhWq-jrYNjYNJ0Ig-OGIzaCJVseyq86-q7sd6yxXG9mo8XgbH44nS+XK1mI8iFXbgYOK5AztBoMYeMrIDM2iuM2iMqoKOAAFQ71g7yA3fBXfA8SCYJMEQ2CJMDAIDUKK88oR8DS7XSAbU6P6CQYyYHYBChL+75XCk95+BeKY9Hoj5DEqAB0B5gKA8B2MgJCYIgRyQBouiYAw2BnE+kQABTiucH5pM82CvAAlJAMTzFAiAnqY0HXnYt4-iEf4PA+honOOSo5LGfCQSRCFRLBgivB8XwZDklEXOBiFwt6pBJmRFGMIx7wAHxMfi4knEwIk8BMCmUcIkALHAOh2FhQHrAARgAVrAWH4ogmxkRZjGqmqCxsYQHGXlxPEiZAyQQXxkB6ugfh2LAPDpmwcKQGRplfLFEIJUlKVvN+QYeV5mCIbAcYCKl-mkUq9GBelcTiQmsCIX4EiCGRsX0eMEY5eZ9VWZ8iXJbAtn2al-BOYBxhfmV3n5v0OUiUGBBthoHQKdFnjeH8fz9c6rVrB1XV1Qh62bR0fVtM16hJX4UnPohDw8Npa0bdIW0pLd7DNWukzTH127qABQHIJJ9U8KocwgKt9WqZ+nz4XgRHnNDunEdRdwPJgIPw0cPBtWd3UiUjv1biAQA)

I recommend substituting the `dataArrayInput` with your data and playing with it in TypeScript Playground until the `printDataAnswers` method works as you expect and returns the values you are looking for. You can then copy it into your existing logic.

```js
// define data interface

interface Data {
    id: string;
    form_id: string;
    ip: string;
    created_at: string;
    updated_at: string | null;
    answers: {
        [key: string]: {
            name: string;
            order: string;
            text: string;
            type: string;
            answer?: string;
        }
    }
}

// example of static data
const dataArrayInput: Data[] = [
    {
        "id": "---",
        "form_id": "---",
        "ip": "---",
        "created_at": "2021-09-18 07:39:14",
        "updated_at": null,
        "answers": {
            "1": {
                "name": "vousAvez",
                "order": "6",
                "text": "QUESTION",
                "type": "control_head"
            },
            "2": {
                "name": "email",
                "order": "7",
                "text": "Email",
                "type": "control_email",
                "answer": "email Address" }
        }
    },
];


/**
 * Iterates through all answers in an array of data and returns and array all the string answers.
 */
function printDataAnswers(dataArray: Data[]) {

// iterate through data and pull out answers
    const allAnswers: string[] = []
    dataArray.forEach((data) => {
        const {answers} = data; // destructure object
        if (answers) {
            // iterate through answer key and values
            for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(answers)) {
                console.log(key);
                const {answer} = value; // destructure object
                const answerOrEmpty = answer || "";
                console.log(answerOrEmpty);        
                allAnswers.push(answerOrEmpty);    
            }
        }
    });

    return allAnswers;
}

const answerArray = printDataAnswers(dataArrayInput);
console.log(answerArray);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this input ! I will study it well to see